# Conditional breakpoint: This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a non-static const method called `size_t A::m() const`, which I want to use to trigger a breakpoint if it returns a value greater than 1. Here is `class A` and instance `a`:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<double> myvec;
    size_t m() const
    {
      return myvec.size();
    }
} a;
```

So I add a breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013 with this condition

```
a.m() > 1 // a is an instance of class A
```

However, when I try to compile this I get the following message from the IDE:

> The following breakpoint cannot be set:
>
> At myFile.cpp, line xxx, when 'a.m() > 1' is true
>
> This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.

Note that `A::m()` does not modify anything, it only calls the `.size()` method of a vector and returns that value, so the assertion that the expression has side effects is simply false. In fact, *replacing* the breakpoint condition with `a.myvec.size() > 1` (ie. the content of the method itself) has the same effect!

Regarding what can be used as a conditional in a breakpoint, [Microsoft says that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Create_breakpoints_that_break_when_you_want);

> The condition can be any valid expression that is recognized by the
>   debugger.

So I went and had a look at [Expressions in the Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/za56x861.aspx), and [found this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a7a250bs.aspx):

> One common cause of side effects is evaluating a function call in a
>   debugger window. Such evaluations are usually noticeable. A more
>   subtle cause of side effects is the evaluation of properties and other
>   implicit function calls in managed code.
>
> The debugger cannot tell whether a property evaluation or implicit
>   function call has side effects. Therefore, by default, the debugger
>   does not evaluate implicit function calls automatically. Property
>   evaluation is allowed by default, but can be turned off in the Options
>   dialog box. When a function call or property has not been evaluated, a
>   refresh icon appears. You can manually evaluate the expression by
>   clicking the refresh icon. For details, see How to: Refresh Watch
>   Values.
>
> When evaluation of properties or implicit function calls is turned
>   off, you can force evaluation by using the ac format modifier (for C#
>   only). See [Format Specifiers in C#.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e514eeby.aspx)

If someone could translate the above paragraph to English that would be great. Can I put functions in these debugger conditionals or not?

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: @dauphic I've added the definition of the entire class and instance

Comment: `a` isn't a pointer and doesn't overload operator `->`.

Comment: @dauphic I fixed it; it's not relevant though this was just an example.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. A workaround is to code an `if` yourself, and the set the breakpoint inside the `if`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my translation of the help link you provided:

- Paragraph 1: calling functions probably has side effects.  Evaluating properties might have side effects.
- Paragraph 2: the debugger can't tell if there are side effects, so we're just going to assume: "functions = bad", "properties = good" (i.e. "functions have side effect, properties do not").  Refresh icon information that isn't relevant to the immediate issue.
- Paragraph 3: want to force the debugger?  If you're using C#, put `,ac` after your evaluation.

So, what it boils down to is, if you want to call a function in your evaluation and are using C#, put `,ac` after it

```
a->m() > 1,ac
```

Since you're using C++, I think this boils down to "No functions in your evaluation statements for you!"  For the purpose of debugging, you *possibly* can remove the const from `A::m`, since the specifier doesn't (shouldn't) have any impact on the logic flow.  I'm not even sure if that will work, though.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I think that `ac` modifier only applies to C# (it doesn't work in c++ - `identifier "ac" is undefined`). Maybe this is just a VC++ limitation then...

Comment: @ausairman Dang, I didn't check your tags, and thought you were in C#.  Yes, you're right, that's one of the more clear things in the help document - `,ac` will only work for C#.  I'll edit my post, but it looks like that means "don't use functions" in your watch.

Comment: Well if that's the case then at the very least the wording of `This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.` constitutes a minor bug (the expression *does not* have side effects!) so I'll file a report.

Comment: @ausairman I doubt Microsoft would like to admit to: `This expression may have side effects.  We don't really know.  Just to be safe, it will not be evaluated.  Upgrade to C# if you want better features.`, but it never hurts to report issues to them.  (I'd almost think their language is so obscure just to help hide that fact. :) )

Comment: If the functions are const, then that should be pretty much a guarantee that they don't have side effects...

Answer (score 10):

Evaluating any function call has side effects, because it induces a change of state, either in registers or the stack, or both. This is exactly what the last paragraph you cited is saying.

In your case, both the registers and stack are changed, assuming standard project settings. A `call` instruction is used to call `m()`, which pushes the instruction pointer to the stack, and the return value is stored in `eax`. On top of these two obvious side effects, the stack and registers are also modified by the prologue/epilogue generated for the calling convention of `m`.

This can be verified by generating a naked function and using inline assembler, which only modifies registers:

```
int __declspec(naked) foo()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 10
        jmp ebx
    }
}

int main()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ebx, cnt
        jmp foo
    }
cnt:
    return 0;
}
```

If you break into the debugger at any point in this application with `foo()` in your watch list, it will display 'This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.'

Comment: Where in the paragraph I posted is that information conveyed?

Comment: It's worded poorly. `One common cause of side effects is evaluating a function call in a debugger window.` This isn't implying that calling a function is often the reason for side effects, it's saying that calling a function induces a side effect.

Comment: I think you've got it - the first reason I've seen that makes sense and explains why even const methods can't be used here.

Answer (score 3):

There are good answers translating the statement but here is a nice hack someone could use.

In your code where you want to add break point, add a line such as

```
auto debug = a.m()
```

Set a breakpoint there, and you can add this in condition

```
debug > 1
```

Or you could do something like this

```
if (a.m() > 1)
    bool debug = 1;
```

and can set a breakpoint in debug line.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but you might want to look at the use of `const` in your method declaration in more depth.  You might want to explicitly state anything that is not to be changed into a const (IIRC correctly const can be used in five different locations in a method declaration so look carefully).

`const` is a contract that the compiler enforces.  If your method accesses any pointer that is not const, it might be a problem. If there is a static variable that might be a problem. It's also possible that while your compiler might be happy that const is fine in your code the IDE might not be as intelligent as the compiler (and thus might want some more `const` assurance).

Without your code, it's kind of hard to tell for sure, but this should give you at least an idea.

For some more reading on `const`, this page seems to have a decent tutorial:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the content of the method in the code, it is completely trivial and unless `std::vector::size()` modifies something then it most certainly does not have side effects!

Comment: What happens if you return something like `(sizet)5` instead and never call the size()?

Comment: Same effect - `This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated.`

Comment: Seems like an issue with VS then.  I'd file a bug on that if you can.  You can't get any more non-side-effect-y than `return 5;` (given you have a const method).

Comment: One last thing you could do would be to make your object const and see if it fails there too...

Comment: A const method can still have side effects, just not in the object of which it's a member. They're trying to avoid the debugger totally altering program flow which is a valid concern. Visual studio assumes all function calls have side effects, whether or not they are declared const. It would be nice if they did some heuristics to allow you to use simple getters in conditional breakpoints.